# tabbar in a tabpanel will shiver when tapped on with sencha touch 2.1

Tags: sencha-touch, tabpanel

I want to create a view with a titlebar and a tabpanel with two lists and a input form,so i 
create a titlebar first and then a tabpanel.But when i taps each tab,all of the tabs will shiver up and down a little and when i config the tabBarPosition to bottom,it looks good.
So,how to solve this ? And,how to clear the default background of the tabBar ?

below is my view ：

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView',
    {
        extend : 'Ext.Container',
        id : 'MyView',
        xtype : 'MyView',
        config : {
            xtype : 'panel',
            layout : 'vbox',
            items : [
                {
                        xtype : 'titlebar',
                        docked : 'top',
                        title : 'MyView',
                        items : [
                            {
                                text : 'goback',
                                ui : 'back',
                                align : 'right',
                                listeners : {
                                    tap : function(){
                                        backwardPage('back');
                                    }
                                }
                            },{
                                text : 'index',
                                ui : 'home',
                                align : 'left',
                                listeners : {
                                    tap : function() {
                                        forwardPage('index','index');
                                    }
                                }
                            }    
                        ]
                }//title bar
                ,{
                            xtype : 'tabpanel',
                            style : 'border:1px solid red;',
                            //tabBarPosition : 'bottom',
                            flex : 1,
                            ui : 'light',
                            layout : {
                                type : 'card',
                                align : 'middle',
                                pack : 'center'
                            },
                            defaults: {
                                styleHtmlContent: true
                            },
                            items : [
                                 {
                                            title : 'One',
                                            html :　'one'
                                 }
                                 , {
                                            title : 'two',
                                            html : 'two'
                                 }
                                ,{
                                            title : 'three',
                                            html :　'three'
                                }
                            ]
                        }//top buttons
            ]
        }//config
});
```